# Check if zip contains files with specific extension using PowerShell without expanding

Tags: windows, powershell, zip

I'm getting ZIP files sent to a server and I use PowerShell to deal with them.
Some files need to be extracted, others don't. It depends on the filetypes inside the ZIP.

Is it possible to check if a ZIP file contains for example PDF files without expanding it?

Comment: I uusally run 7-zip from PS and it has a -l option to list files : https://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/cmdline/commands/list.htm

Comment: linked answer shows you how you can read the contents of your zip with a custom function